# How do I solve HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am running CakePHP 1.3 setup on a windows 10 PC with Visual Studio Code. I have configured VSCode to use an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=warren-buckley.iis-express) for IIS Express to enable both run and debug for web application using Vscode and IIS Express.

When I open the application folder using vscode and run the cakePHP application using  said command for the extension i get the error message How do I solve HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

In output i can see IIS Express server running in the , see print screen below
[image]

when call the URl http://localhost:11386/index.php on chrome i get Internal Server Error, see print screen when accessing the application on chrome below

[image]

Comment: View your error logs .. Or put error handling code at the top of your index.php: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
`

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: the issue is not specific to PHP as same application work fine in IIS server, but does not work when using IIS Express via the vscode extension. however i have included error_reporting and this does not return or output errors

Comment: Then what do your server logs say?  This WILL be reported SOMEWHERE ..

Comment: CakePHP1.3? Quite an old version ...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it as it seems the root cause for the HTTP Internal Error was IIS Express was not enabled to use PHP.

To enable PHP on IIS Express, install PHP and update applicationhost.config in
(%userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config)

In the applicationhost.config file search for `<fastCgi/>` tag entry and replace it with the below, pointing to the directory where your PHP has been installed

```
<fastCgi>
    <application fullPath="C:\Program Files\PHP\v5.6.0\php-cgi.exe" />
</fastCgi>
```

with this settings, Visual Studio Code is able to run PHP applications using [this VSCode IIS Express  extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=warren-buckley.iis-express)